# Prestashop employee removed randomly

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

we are running a prestashop store and we face the following issue.
In random moments the employee that tries to login is removed from the database. The same happens when i try to disable an employee from the backoffice. This issue came up to version 1.6.1.3. I just updated prestashop to 1.6.1.6 but the issue still exists. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  For this particular question, you should try the [forums at prestashop.com](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/).

Comment: hi tomas. i have tried forge.prestashop.com but i had no luck there. noone answered my issue, so i wanted to try here where more people post their problems. I am going to to try there too, but any help here is appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed some particular modules? In so many years that I work with prestashop this is the first time that I hear this strange issue :).

Comment: There are many modules installed in this setup, but this issue started at a time where the system did not change for about a month. I have set a cronjob to restore employees, but this is not a real solution.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed this behavior is very unusual and definitely not coming from the core of the application.

As suggested @sarcom, to better understand if this is due to a module or something different, I would recommend adding a delete() method in /classes/Employee.php:

```
public function delete()
{
    $log = print_r(debug_backtrace(), true);
    file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/../employee_delete_'.time().'.log', $log);

    parent::delete();
}
```

That way, every time an employee will be deleted, it will create a detailed log file in your PrestaShop folder (e.g. /employee_delete_xxx.log), helping to identify the script or module which triggered the deletion.

To make sure this works, once the method in place, try to delete an employee by yourself, using the PrestaShop admin panel (e.g. "Administration" / "Employees").

If employee still get deleted and no log file is created, this would mean the action was performed by an external script, accessing directly the database, without communicating with PrestaShop.